# Convert all numbers to positives in a List of integers

Tags: c#, .net, linq

If I have a list of both positive and negative integers:

```
var values = new List<int> { -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30 };
```

How do I convert all the values to positive numbers?

```
var values = new List<int> { 30, 20, 10, 0, 10, 20, 30 };
```

I know I could use `intValue = intValue * -1` but that would only convert the negatives to positives and vice versa. Besides, if possible I would like to do this using LINQ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Math.Abs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk4666yx(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var positives = values.Select(i => Math.Abs(i)).ToList();
```

Or the shortened form using method group syntax (as mentioned by @CommuSoft in the comments):

```
var positives = values.Select(Math.Abs).ToList();
```

Comment: A small improvement can be to use an *eta reduction*: `Math.Abs` instead of `i => Math.Abs(i)`. But +1.

Comment: @CommuSoft Yeah, but that syntax can be confusing to people. I'll include it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
values.Select(Math.Abs).ToList();
```

Or

```
values.Select(n => n < 0 ? -n : n).ToList();
```

Or (fastest way)

```
values.Select(n => n & int.MaxValue).ToList();
```

Comment: Mind that the second - although semantically correct - can be much slower: many compilers can generate a branch-free *absolute value*. +1 nevertheless.